# SSIS - Move data from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, move

I have to move data from SQL Server to MySQL using SSIS. I've got [this tutorial](http://crushthesoul.com/node/43), but I couldn't find ODBC Destination in Visual Studio 2008. is there another way to move data from SQL Server to MySQL?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96a2c8d9-6a9e-4f31-9449-0712f9bc2cbc/odbc-destination-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: oke thankyou for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODBC destination was added in SQL 2012.  Visual Studio 2008 (or really BIDS 2008) works with SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2, which are prior versions.

However, you can still do this in 2008 using and ODBC driver and the ADO.NET Destination.  Read more about that here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/03/04/connecting-to-mysql-from-ssis/

m

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Script task to load the data from SQL server to MySQL

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim sSql As String = "select s.PROTOCOL_SUBJECT_ID, s.PROTOCOL_ID, s.SEQUENCE_NUMBER, s.ORGANIZATION_ID" & vbCrLf &
                "from dim_subject s" & vbCrLf &
                "where s.ORGANIZATION_ID <> 2"

    Dim sCn As String = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Option=3;Server=Server1;Port=3306;Database=DB1;User=User1;Password=Pass1;"
    Dim cnMySql As New Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(sCn)
    cnMySql.Open()

    Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=ResFinCt;Initial Catalog=OnCore;User ID=saddd;Password=dsfsf;")
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sSql, cn)
    Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    While dr.Read
        Dim PROTOCOL_SUBJECT_ID As String = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("PROTOCOL_SUBJECT_ID")).ToString()
        Dim PROTOCOL_ID As String = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("PROTOCOL_ID")).ToString()
        Dim SEQUENCE_NUMBER As String = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("SEQUENCE_NUMBER")).ToString()
        Dim ORGANIZATION_ID As String = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("ORGANIZATION_ID")).ToString()

        sSql = "insert into stg_subject(PROTOCOL_SUBJECT_ID, PROTOCOL_ID, SEQUENCE_NUMBER, ORGANIZATION_ID) values(" &
             PROTOCOL_SUBJECT_ID & ", " &
             PROTOCOL_ID & ", '" &
             SEQUENCE_NUMBER & "', " &
             ORGANIZATION_ID & ")"

        Dim cmdMySql As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sSql, cnMySql)
        cmdMySql.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End While

    dr.Close()
    cnMySql.Close()

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```